# Do you know a more elegant way to calculate number of events on preceeding days?

Tags: r, data.table

I'd like your thoughts on a more elegant way to work out the number of events that have occured in preceeding days. My code (below) works, but it is not very nice, or scalable. I'm trying to get to the table at the bottom (desired_table).  Any thoughts?

I would like to calculate the sum of events in the preceeding days in a more elegant manner than this.

```r
require(data.table)

# simulating an example data.table
date <- c("2000-01-01", "2000-01-04", "2000-01-05", "2000-01-06", "2000-01-01", "2000-01-02", "2000-01-03", "2000-01-04", "2000-01-05", "2000-01-06" , "2000-01-01", "2000-01-04", "2000-01-05", "2000-01-06", "2000-01-01", "2000-01-02", "2000-01-03", "2000-01-04", "2000-01-05", "2000-01-06")

cohort <- c("a", "b", "c")

zz <- data.table(DATE = date, COHORT = cohort)
zz$DATE <- as.Date(zz$DATE)  # making sure the date is in the correct format

# adding on some other date fields so we can summarise by these days as well
zz$d1 <- zz$DATE +1  # will become "yesterday" when joined
zz$d2 <- zz$DATE +2  # will become "day before yesterday", when joined 

# summarising the data for the first date
summary1 <- zz[,list(events_today = .N ), by= c("DATE", "COHORT")]

# summarising the data for the previous
summary2 <- zz[,list(events_yesterday  = .N ), by= c("d1", "COHORT")]

# summarising the data for the day before yesterday
summary3 <- zz[,list(events_day_before_yesterday  = .N ), by= c("d2", "COHORT")]

# merging the tables together
summary1.2 <- merge(summary1, summary2, by.x = c("DATE", "COHORT"), by.y = c("d1", "COHORT"), all = TRUE)

# merging the tables together to join on third summary table.
desired_table <- merge(summary1.2, summary3, by.x = c("DATE", "COHORT"), by.y = c("d2", "COHORT"), all = TRUE)

print(desired_table)
```

There has to be a more elegant way to do this?
My example here is trivial - in practice I may want to do this for many thousands records, and many time periods.

Comment: Since it's working code, this question rather belongs on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Running your code gives a warning "Item 2 is of size 3 but maximum size is 20 (recycled leaving remainder of 2 items)". Further, I do not understand how you define whether there an event on a day or not.

Comment: @schwantke Yes, data.table warns aggressively about recycling, I don't think that indicates anything wrong with the example. From the code, the number of events is defined as `.N`, so each row is an event. The number of events on a day is the number of rows with that date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think a more elegant way would be

```
long_zz <- melt(zz, id.vars = "COHORT")
new_zz <- dcast(long_zz, COHORT + value ~ variable, fun = length, drop = FALSE, fill = NA)
new_zz
#     COHORT      value DATE d1 d2
#  1:      a 2000-01-01    1 NA NA
#  2:      a 2000-01-02    1  1 NA
#  3:      a 2000-01-03    1  1  1
#  4:      a 2000-01-04   NA  1  1
#  5:      a 2000-01-05    2 NA  1
#  6:      a 2000-01-06    2  2 NA
#  7:      a 2000-01-07   NA  2  2
#  8:      a 2000-01-08   NA NA  2
#  9:      b 2000-01-01    2 NA NA
# 10:      b 2000-01-02   NA  2 NA
# 11:      b 2000-01-03    1 NA  2
# 12:      b 2000-01-04    2  1 NA
# 13:      b 2000-01-05   NA  2  1
# 14:      b 2000-01-06    2 NA  2
# 15:      b 2000-01-07   NA  2 NA
# 16:      b 2000-01-08   NA NA  2
# 17:      c 2000-01-01    1 NA NA
# 18:      c 2000-01-02    1  1 NA
# 19:      c 2000-01-03   NA  1  1
# 20:      c 2000-01-04    2 NA  1
# 21:      c 2000-01-05    2  2 NA
# 22:      c 2000-01-06   NA  2  2
# 23:      c 2000-01-07   NA NA  2
# 24:      c 2000-01-08   NA NA NA
#     COHORT      value DATE d1 d2
```

Here, I first transform the data from a wide format to a long one and then use caste to split the variables (DATE, d1, d2) into columns again, while counting the number of rows in each COHORT, value group for each variable. 
Without `drop = FALSE`, we would miss row 24, where no events happend for COHORT c.

You can set your names with

```
setnames(new_zz, c("value", "DATE", "d1", "d2"), c("DATE", "events_today","events_yesterday","events_day_before_yesterday"))
```

`mircobenchmark`-results of your approach (merge) vs. mine (long_wide):

```
Unit: milliseconds
      expr       min        lq     mean    median        uq      max neval
     merge 14.740983 18.534281 31.88430 21.223305 31.830966 353.3662   100
 long_wide  5.102077  6.411999 10.82941  7.130821  8.884161 117.7351   100
```

Comment: Great answer! Much cleaner than what I was working on. I'd add as a note to OP that a more general way to create the extra date columns in `zz` would be something like `date_adds = 1:2; zz[, paste0("d", date_adds) := lapply(date_adds, "+", DATE)]`. That way they don't have to copy/paste/modify `zz$d2 <- zz$DATE +2`, `zz$d3 <- zz$DATE +3`, etc., in case they need more than just two lags.

Comment: Thank you Kath. This looks amazing. I am getting the following error though after the new_zz line :   `new_zz <- dcast(long_zz, COHORT + value ~ variable, fun = length, drop = FALSE, fill = NA)`       
`Error in vapply(indices, fun, .default) : values must be type 'logical',
 but FUN(X[[1]]) result is type 'integer'` Any idea on how to solve this? Many thanks indeed.

Comment: Hi again - I solved this error by starting a new R session (without so many other packages loaded).  Thanks so very much - it works perfectly.